# Estructura del switch evitar que muestre sentencias

Tags: java

Poseo este pequeño codigo en java /estoy empezando a aprender/

```
package com.switchtuto;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class switchcase2 {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("menu de opciones");
    System.out.println("1: Sumar");
    System.out.println("2: Restar");
    System.out.println("3: Multiplicar");
    System.out.println("4: Dividir");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("ingrese su opcion");
    int opcion = scanner.nextInt();

    if(opcion>=1 && opcion<=4){
    System.out.println("Ingrese el primer numero");
    int x = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ingrese el segundo numero");
    int y = scanner.nextInt();
    int resultado = 0;

switch (opcion) {
case 1:
resultado= x+y;
break;
case 2:
resultado = x-y;
break;
case 3:
resultado = x*y;
break;
case 4:
resultado =x/y;
break;
default:
    System.out.println("Tu Eres Loco");
    break;
}
System.out.println("Resultado:");
System.out.println(resultado);
}

}
}
```

y quisiera que el programa no mostrara los mensajes de pedir numero cuando el caso sea el default, porque primero pide los numeros y luego colocado cualquier numero muestra la advertencia.

Codigo final:

```
package com.paquetes;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class switchcase2 {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("menu de opciones");
    System.out.println("1: Sumar");
    System.out.println("2: Restar");
    System.out.println("3: Multiplicar");
    System.out.println("4: Dividir");
    System.out.println();


     int opcion=0,x=0,y=0,resultado=0;

    do
    {
     System.out.println("Ingrese Opción Válida");
     opcion = scanner.nextInt();
    }while((opcion<1) || (opcion>4)); 

    System.out.println("Ingrese el primer numero");
    x = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ingrese el segundo numero");
    y = scanner.nextInt();

    switch (opcion) {
case 1:
resultado= x+y;
break;
case 2:
resultado = x-y;
break;
case 3:
resultado = x*y;
break;
case 4:
resultado =x/y;
break;
default:
    System.out.println("Tu Eres LOCO5");
    break;
}
System.out.println("Resultado:");
System.out.println(resultado);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias utilizar la Intrucción hacer-Mientras  (do while) para validar la entrada de la opción y no saldrá del bucle mientras la opción esté entre 1 y 4
y para evitar que se cuelgue el programa por Exceptions como `NumberFormatException` , añadir un `try{ } catch(){}`

```
 int opcion=0,x=0,y=0,resultado=0;
  do
  {
   System.out.println("Ingrese Opción Válida");
    try
    {
     opcion = Integer.parseInt(scanner.next());
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException ex){
     System.out.println("No es Número , Verificar su Entrada "+  ex.getMessage());
    }
}
while(opcion<1 || opcion >4);
    // Verifico si no está en el rango si retorna verdadero regresa al hacer
    //luego solicito números si sale del ciclo es porque tengo una opción correcta


System.out.println("Ingrese el primer numero");
 x = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("Ingrese el segundo numero");
 y = scanner.nextInt();


switch (opcion) {...}
System.out.println("Resultado "  + resultado);
```

Comment: si meto 3 no funciona, solo si meto 5

Comment: Si ingresas tres es una opción válida que seria multiplicar y avanza a solicitar la entrada de los dos números si es menor de 1 y mayor de 4 es incorrecto y se vuelve recursivo hasta que se ingrese una entrada correcta

Comment: ya lo corregi, tenia algo malo jejeje

Answer (score 2):

Esta es la solución a tu problema, en base al análisis de tu código.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("menu de opciones");
    System.out.println("1: Sumar");
    System.out.println("2: Restar");
    System.out.println("3: Multiplicar");
    System.out.println("4: Dividir");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("ingrese su opcion");
    int opcion = scanner.nextInt();

    if(opcion>=1 && opcion<=4){
        System.out.println("Ingrese el primer numero");
        int x = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el segundo numero");
        int y = scanner.nextInt();
        int resultado = 0;

        switch (opcion) {...}

        System.out.println("Resultado:" + resultado);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Tu Eres Loco");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

si entendí tu pregunta quieres que si el usuario pone un numero diferente de 1,2,3, o 4 no muestre los mensajes de pedir números,si es asi podrias poner eso en un if

```
         System.out.println("ingrese su opcion");
        int opcion = scanner.nextInt();
        //inicializo y declaro las varibles
        int x = 0, y = 0, resultado = 0;
        //si es opcion valida pido los valores por teclado
        if (opcion >= 1 && opcion <= 4) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese el primer numero");
             x = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese el segundo numero");
             y = scanner.nextInt();

        }

        switch (opcion) { //codigo que ya tienes


}
```

Comment: con esta opcion funciona, pero ya no estaria usando el codigo dentro del switch, queria era ver si era posible condicionando el switch case para que se cumpla el default case, ya que este quedaria inutilizado

Comment: no entiendo a que te refieres con que no estarías usando el codigo dentro del switch, podrías ser un poco mas claro :)!!!

Comment: creo entender ya lo que dices, debes sacar el if fuera del switch, y declarar las variables x, y, y resultado antes del if, modificare la respuesta para que entiendas un poco de lo que me refiero!

Comment: En teoría si, pero el if evita pedir los datos en una opción no valida, que esa era la pregunta de tu post!!!